# Connecting RabbitMQ | Pika | Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, devops, pika

I have a kubernetes cluster running. Inside this I have python application running as a pod.

This app is talking to `rabbitmq` which is also one of the pods of the same cluster. So the whole connection is done using internal IPs.

The problem is I have a service for rabbitmq, so I am providing the service IP for connection. It looks something like this ( with pika )

```
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rabbituser, rabbitpass)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=QHost, port=80, credentials=credentials))
channel = connection.channel()
```

As you can see the connection I am trying to make is to port 80 which is open in the k8s service.

Now it should redirect it to respective pod which is rabbitmq, but it is trying to connect to port `5672`

That means, error is because it is trying to connect to `service-ip:5672`, which is not there.

I want it to forward the request to the rabbit mq pod where the service is pointed.

I hope that I have explained main things.

Please ask if more details required.
Thanks

Comment: Could you provide YAML of your RabbitMQ service? I think problem in misconfiguration.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, could not respond earlier due to personal emergency. I have not figured out the load balancer issue, I am using container IP for now as every communication is internal. But this will be an issue if I restart the container as I will have the new IPs.
Here is the service file : (sorry for the bad format, I am new here) 



**kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: rabbit
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5672**

Comment: What version of K8s you use?